# Цветной текст в QMenuBar

Tags: python, pyqt5, pyqt, qss, qmenubar

Как мне вывести цветной текст в `menu_bar`?

Пробовал через `Colorama` - ничего не получилось.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QMainWindow, QTextEdit, QMenuBar, QApplication
from PyQt5.QtCore import QObject
from PyQt5.QtCore import pyqtSignal as Signal
  
  
class OutputLogger(QObject):
    emit_write = Signal(str, int)
  
    class Severity:
        DEBUG = 0
        ERROR = 1
  
    def __init__(self, io_stream, severity):
        super().__init__()
         self.io_stream = io_stream
        self.severity = severity
  
    def write(self, text):
        self.io_stream.write(text)
        self.emit_write.emit(text, self.severity)
  
    def flush(self):
        self.io_stream.flush()
  
  
import sys
OUTPUT_LOGGER_STDOUT = OutputLogger(sys.stdout, OutputLogger.Severity.DEBUG)
OUTPUT_LOGGER_STDERR = OutputLogger(sys.stderr, OutputLogger.Severity.ERROR)
  
sys.stdout = OUTPUT_LOGGER_STDOUT
sys.stderr = OUTPUT_LOGGER_STDERR
  
  
class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.text_edit = QTextEdit()
  
        OUTPUT_LOGGER_STDOUT.emit_write.connect(self.append_log)
        OUTPUT_LOGGER_STDERR.emit_write.connect(self.append_log)
  
        menu_bar = QMenuBar()
        menu = menu_bar.addMenu('Say')
        menu.addAction('hello', lambda: print('Hello!'))
        menu.addAction('fail', lambda: print('Fail!', file=sys.stderr))
        self.setMenuBar(menu_bar)
  
        self.setCentralWidget(self.text_edit)
  
    def append_log(self, text, severity):
        text = repr(text)
        if severity == OutputLogger.Severity.ERROR:
            self.text_edit.append('<b>{}</b>'.format(text))
        else:
            self.text_edit.append(text)
  
  
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication([])
    mw = MainWindow()
    mw.show()
    print('Go!')
    app.exec()
```

Comment: Объясните пожалуйста лучше, что вы хотите сделать, а лучше как-то покажите, как то что вы хотите сделать, должно выглядеть.

Comment: @S.Nick Чтобы текст при выводе в меню бар  был цветным

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Поиграйтесь со `Style Sheet`

```
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets, QtCore, QtGui


class Window(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Window, self).__init__()

        mainMenu = self.menuBar()
        mainMenu.setNativeMenuBar(False)
        self.fileMenu = mainMenu.addMenu('Menu1')

        action1 = QtWidgets.QWidgetAction(self)             
        self.label1 = QtWidgets.QLabel("action1")
        action1.setDefaultWidget(self.label1);
        action1.setText('action1')
        
        action2 = QtWidgets.QWidgetAction(self)             
        self.label2 = QtWidgets.QLabel("action2")
        action2.setDefaultWidget(self.label2);
        action2.setText('action2')

        action3 = QtWidgets.QWidgetAction(self)             
        self.label3 = QtWidgets.QLabel("action3")
        action3.setDefaultWidget(self.label3);
        action3.setText('action3')
        
        self.fileMenu.addAction(action1)
        self.fileMenu.addAction(action2)
        self.fileMenu.addAction(action3)

        self.fileMenu.triggered.connect(self.print_stuff)        

    def print_stuff(self, q):
        print('whatever->', q.text() )
        
        self.label1.setStyleSheet("""
            QLabel { background-color : #ABABAB; padding: 10px 12px 10px 12px;}
            QLabel:hover { background-color: #654321;}
        """)
        self.label2.setStyleSheet("""
            QLabel { background-color : #ABABAB; padding: 10px 12px 10px 12px;}
            QLabel:hover { background-color: #654321;}
        """)
        self.label3.setStyleSheet("""
            QLabel { background-color : #ABABAB; padding: 10px 12px 10px 12px;}
            QLabel:hover { background-color: #654321;}
        """)

        if q.text() == 'action1':
            self.label1.setStyleSheet("""
                QLabel { background-color : red; padding: 10px 12px 10px 12px;}
                QLabel:hover { background-color: #C10000;}
            """)
        elif q.text() == 'action2':
            self.label2.setStyleSheet("""
                QLabel { background-color : red; padding: 10px 12px 10px 12px;}
                QLabel:hover { background-color: #C10000;}
            """)
        elif q.text() == 'action3':
            self.label3.setStyleSheet("""
                QLabel { background-color : red; padding: 10px 12px 10px 12px;}
                QLabel:hover { background-color: #C10000;}
            """)


qss = """
QMenuBar {
    background-color: qlineargradient(x1:0, y1:0, x2:0, y2:1,
                                      stop:0 lightgray, stop:1 darkgray);
}
QMenuBar::item {
    spacing: 3px;           
    padding: 2px 10px;
    background-color: rgb(210,105,30);
    color: rgb(255,255,255);  
    border-radius: 5px;
}
QMenuBar::item:selected {    
    background-color: rgb(244,164,96);
}
QMenuBar::item:pressed {
    background: rgb(128,0,0);
}

QLabel { 
    background-color: #ABABAB;
    color: rgb(255,255,255);
    font: 12px;
    padding: 10px 12px 10px 12px;
} 
QLabel:hover { 
    background-color: #654321;
} 
"""


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    app.setStyleSheet(qss)                                       # <---   
    w = Window()
    w.resize(500, 300)
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]